# How can i attach a value from Json Data to an Actionlink in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, razor-2

The data got from Json  i used to append to a table as rows.First data of the column needs to come in Link format.So i used ActionLink .But i get the following error as "The name 'Transaction_No' does not exist in the current context".

```
function CreateGrid(result) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });


    for (i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        var chk_row = true;
        $('#tbl_RoleMenu tbody').empty().append('<tr id="tr-' + i + '"></tr>');
         String Transaction_No = result.data[i].Loan.toString();

        $('#tr-' + i).append('<td id="tdLoan-' + i + '"> @Html.ActionLink(Transaction_No, "Create", "Portfolio", null, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "emailDialog" }) </td>');
        $('#tr-' + i).append('<td id="tdLoan-1' + i + '">' + result.data[i].Loan + '</td>');

    }   


}
```

Comment: enclose `Transaction_No` inside the double quotes like "Transaction_No"

Comment: @dakait :If we put in double Quotes its just print the text not value.  I want to get this value(result.data[i].Loan.toString()) instead of displaying just transactionno,and need to attach action link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be completely mixing server side code with client side javascript. Try fixing this mess:

```
function CreateGrid(result) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    for (i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        var chk_row = true;
        $('#tbl_RoleMenu tbody').empty().append('<tr id="tr-' + i + '"></tr>');
        var transactionNumber = result.data[i].Loan;

        $('#tr-' + i).append('<td id="tdLoan-' + i + '"><a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Portfolio")" class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="emailDialog">' + transactionNumber + '</a></td>');
        $('#tr-' + i).append('<td id="tdLoan-1' + i + '">' + result.data[i].Loan + '</td>');
    }   
}
```

As an alternative to this horrible mess I would recommend you create this markup on your server using a partial view. I guess that you are calling this function after performing an AJAX request to a controller action (that currently returns a `JsonResult`). Modify this controller action so that instead of returning a JsonResult returns a PartialView and then simply inject this new markup into your DOM.